# How to sort a part of a vector?

Tags: sorting, rust

In C++ We can easily sort a part of an vector By

> sort(A.begin()+start,A.begin()+end);

But in Rust I can not find a good method,Can Anyone Help me??

Comment: Semantics: if it's begin /and/ end, then it's start /and/ __finish__. But here, you add a size (offset, length), not a start position.

Answer (score 11):

You can call [sort()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) on a mutable slice, such as a section of your vector like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<u32> = vec![7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    v[2..5].sort();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f5683ce4b2ff012e21e0afbd00dead9))

Comment: [You don't need the `&mut` there](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f5683ce4b2ff012e21e0afbd00dead9)

Comment: @Aiden4 good catch, thanks!

Comment: Aside: prefer `sort_unstable()` unless stability is required.